# How can I display HTML signature block in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: html, image-display, digital-signature

The email signature blocks I have are in HTML. I am trying to display them in my "Signature" page for a team so that they can access and edit as needed in the Document Library.

I can't figure out how to put pure HTML live so that they can go in and edit HTML to have changes as opposed to putting an image file of the signature. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Multi line of text column with Rich text editing enable. This will give you rich text editing capability using ribbon. User can copy paste formatted text  and also can edit HTML if required.

Comment: How do I enable rich text editing? Is this inside a column?
Right now I tried to create a column and under "type of information in this column" I do see a 'multiple lines of text' option but I dont know where the 'rich text editing' enabled option is... help?